# Multiple Users working in a same SharePoint project

Tags: sharepoint, project-management

I want to know how can multiple users work in a SharePoint project? How can we keep the code sync?

How can multiple users work in a same SharePoint Server? If one guy IISRESETs the other guy gets affected. How is it done?

Thank you.

NLV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are talking about IIRESET I assume you are talking about multiple developers sharing a single SharePoint development server and not multiple end users.

Although this is not impossible it is generally discouraged to share a development server as that could lead to unexpected results. Multiple web.config or other changes could conflct with each other and waiting for SharePoint to spin up after each reset will be really annoying.

Comment: So how is it done actually? If you consider a winforms application, either VSS or TFS can be used to work in the same application, keep the code sync, run and test the applications at the same time. How is it actually done in SharePoint?

Comment: It's done in the exact same way. You keep your code in sync while every one has his own SharePoint environment.

Comment: I have the feeling NLV is doing customisation using SharePoint Designer, in which case there is no easy way to use VSS/TFS. Still I would recommend a local dev installation and then perhaps a 3rd party tool to sync any changes. Pretty horrible. 
When using SharePoint 2010 then you can package up SharePoint Designer changes into a WSP file.

Comment: Muhimbi, we never do changes in SP Designer. We do all our works through features (which is highly recommended). I understood it anyway. Each and every dev should have their own MOSS Server to work on. Thank you.